# Animate UILabel value increment

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uiview, nstimer

I'm trying to increment a percentage view using the following code:

```
// Progress
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        for (float percent = 0.0; percent <= 0.86; percent+=0.01) {
            NSLog(@"%f", percent);
            self.circularProgress2.progress = percent;
        }
    }];
```

It doesn't animate, it goes straight to the final value. I know I can use `NSTimer`:

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0001 target:self selector:@selector(onLableAnimateTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

And then change the value from inside the called method. But I have several bars on the same view, so I guess using the first option would be better for me.

If not possible, how would I duplicate the `NSTimer` behavior without having to create `properties` and methods for every progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code inside the animation-block will be executed which is your case is a for-loop. Consider the following case:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
   CGRect f = aView.frame;
   f.origin.x = 20;
   f.origin.x = 25;
   f.origin.x = 40;
   aView.frame = f;
}];
```

This will animate the view from it's current position to x = 40. Not animate to 20, then to 25, then to 40. The result of the block is that aViews frames origin.x should be 40, no matter what happened before that.

I'd say use a timer if you want to auto-increment the progress with a given interval. You can still animate the change of course (for example by overriding the setProgress-method on your Progress-view class and call an animation from there), but don't use an animation block to increment the model value (progress).

Comment: Thanks. I understand, so there's no way I can use this, right? The best option would be `NSTimer` then, right?

Comment: See my edited answer ;) An animation block and a NSTimer have two different purposes.